# WebClient DownloadString method stops downloading string after few hours of running

Tags: c#, api, cloud, webclient, system.net

I have an EXE which downloads string from an API hosted on cloud. this exe serves well upto one or two hours, it downloads all the string from requested URI but after certain requests/ one to two hours,, it does not download any string. I also tried with DownloadStringAsync method but same behavior with that as well. Following is the code.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                using (var webClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    webClient.Headers.Clear();
                    webClient.Headers.Add("MyId", "037a1289-a1c6-e611-80d9-000d3a213f57");
                    webClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    string downloadedString = webClient.DownloadString(new Uri("https://mycloudapiurl.com/api/MySet/GetMySets?id=D6364A82-9A3C-E711-80E0-000D3A213F57"));
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(downloadedString) && downloadedString != "null")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Downloaded " + i + "times");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Downloaded string is null for API URL");
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
        }
```

this execution stops after around 100 to 120 iterations. The same thing occurs in my real application. not able to figure out the cause which stops downloading after certain iterations

Comment: Did you try to let it run when you debug to get any console/error output? 
Such behavior can be assigned to memory issues. But without Log/Error, hard to diagnostic. To do a quick test, reduce the Thread.Sleep time

Comment: Is it possible the problem is with the server, rather than your code?

Comment: Investigate any throttling/limits imposed by the Cloud provider on unattended downloads.

Comment: Download Fiddler and let it show you the actual HTTP traffic flowing from your computer to the server. This will help you identify whether your request is being handled by the server or not, and whether or not it is your code that is faulty or the server.

Comment: @Leze I reduced Thread.Sleep(10) and it downloaded upto 4000 times,, and then i manually stopped it,, but when i again turned Thread.Sleep(10000) then it stopped after 36 iteration

Comment: Did you get any output message?

Comment: no,, the execution stops at following line only.  --->> string downloadedString = webClient.DownloadString(new Uri("https://mycloudapiurl.com/api/MySet/GetMySets?id=D6364A82-9A3C-E711-80E0-000D3A213F57"));